# Doctrine - how to empty list of used repositories

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine, repository

`DefaultRepositoryFactory` in Doctrine has a private `$repositoryList` property. How do I clear it, once it has some entries?
Clearing any of the metadata/query caches doesn't help with that one.

I have a system/scenario in which I am dynamically mapping the entities to the database tables. At some point, I need to remap them to another set of tables and after that remap, the doctrine still remembers all the previously set/read data (the results, the metadata and the queries).
I can remove the data that is **cached** but I'm not sure how to remove the list of repositories that are actually loaded in this `repositoryList` property.

Since the above mentioned property holds a list of repositories, in that list is also the matching Metadata for each repo, with (at certain point) wrong/old table names.

*(I'm trying to be brief about this as possible, but if it doesn't help you with having an answer, I'll go wider)*

Comment: One way that I see for going around that list of already used repositories would be using a "new" entity manager (so let's say one new manager for each "set" of different target tables that I use), which would then force the usage of a different repository list - but that seem even more hacky...

Comment: I am a bit skeptical as to why you feel you need to clear this list and I suspect you will run into other unit of work issues but having said that, all you need to do is to write your own RepositoryFactory that implements the repository factory interface.  In other words, clone the default one, add some sort of clearRepositories method then plug it in to your config.

Comment: I hear you (and share your skepticism :)). I actually went that way now and already stumbled on some issues... but we'll see. The situation regarding the original setup is not really optimal, when taking into account the current user's requests - apparently we need to get "creative".